Is it possible to construct a group if you know the base of an action of the group?
In "Permutation Groups" by Dixon and Mortimer, at the start of section 3.3 it mentions a linear transformation is completely determined by how it acts on a basis. Then it says an analogous idea is that of a base:
If a group G acts on $ \Omega $ then $ \Sigma \subseteq \Omega $ is a base if the pointwise stabilizer of $ \Sigma $ is $ \{ 1_G \} $.
So is it possible to completely determine a group just from finding a base of one of its actions? As in find the group's order, describe what elements in contains, some elements that generate it etc? If so, how?
Since the book is discussing permutation groups, maybe it is helpful to consider our group we want to determine to be $ H \leq S_{n} $ acting naturally on $ \{ 1 , \dots , n \} $ for some $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ and therefore our base some subset of $ \{ 1 , \dots , n \} $.

No, for example ${1,…,n}$ is a base for all subgroups of Sn. Even if you use an irredundant base it is false — there are, up to renumbering! Only n-1 different bases, but many more different groups.

he analogue of the property of a linear map being determined by its action on a basis of a vector space is that an element $g$ of a given group $G$ is determined by its action on a base of $G$.
